# Post a form using Jquery ajax and get the response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm using this code to post a form using jquery ajax .
my problem is that i want to make php code to be like this:

```
if (isset($_POST[''])) {
// some code here
}
```

this is the javascript code:

```
$("button#submit").click( function() { 
  if( $("#username").val() == "" || $("#password").val() == "" )
    $("div#status").html("Please enter your Email");
  else
    $.post( $("#myForm").attr("action"), $("#myForm :input").serializeArray(),function(data) {
              $("div#status").html(data);
            });

    $("#myForm").submit( function() {
       return false;    
    });

});
```

Comment: are you getting js error message in console?

Comment: no nothing , the code work fine , i test it to modify something in database and the code modify it , the only problem is in the response ,

Comment: What's the problem with the response?  Is your PHP code `echo`ing anything?

Comment: What is the current code you have for PHP? And what are you actually asking for from this post? If you are asking for someone to write the PHP code that would be required to process the POST from an Ajax call to PHP, it would be a good idea to also provide the HTML contents for the form element, inclusive, that will be posted, so we can see what HTML elements are actually getting serialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you tested the code, and the php section works fine, but you can not get a response in jquery, then, you should check your php code(It should be like this):

```
if (isset($_POST[''])) {
$data = "";
// some code here to fill $data
echo $data; // this is the actual response to the jquery interface.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 6 b's in php file name but 7 b's in ajax url.

```
url: "bbbbbbb.php",  <--- 7 b's

bbbbbb.php  <--- 6 b's
```

Plus, along with success you should have error also so you'd see what the error is.

```
error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
   alert(textStatus);
}
```

Comment: that just an example not the real name

Comment: Then add the error handler to view the actual error. I have updated the answer to include error code.

Comment: the code work fine , i test it to modify something in database and the code modify it , the only problem is in the response

Answer (score 0):

Despite a lack of actual question, here's a crack at an answer.

The first issue is that the javascript, while working, won't get to do the complete job it's supposed to do.  The javascript code appears to want to prevent the form from being manually submitted via the submit event.  You may want to reorganise the javascript to look like:

```
$("#myForm").submit( function() {
   return false;    
});

$("button#submit").click( function() { 
  if( $("#username").val() == "" || $("#password").val() == "" ) {
    $("div#status").html("Please enter your Email");
  } else {
    $.post( $("#myForm").attr("action"), $("#myForm :input").serializeArray(),function(data) {
      $("div#status").html(data);
    });
  }
});
```

Additionally, you may want to look up usage of modern event watching in jquery, and the usage of `.on()`. i.e. `$("#myForm").on("submit", function() {});`.  But that's not quite the point of this post.

As for the PHP code, let's infer you have the following HTML form:

```
<form action="login.php" id="myForm">
    <label for="username">Username: </label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" />
    <label for="password">Password: </label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" />
    <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<div id="status">Please provide username and password to login</div>
```

In login.php, you would have

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == 'submit') {
        // validate $_POST contains username and password
        ...

        // sanitize username and password
        $username = sanitize($_POST['username']);
        $password = sanitize($_POST['password']);

        // do my processing
        // doLogin returns true for successful login, or message contain error string
        $result = doLogin($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);

        if ($result === true) {
           echo 'You have successfully logged in';
        } else {
           echo $result;
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Unknown form action';
    }
} else {
    // do GET processing 
}
```

With this, just echo the response you want to appear in the div#status.